# Using Objective-C++ static library in straight Objective-C target

Tags: xcode, static-libraries, objective-c++, libstdc++

I build a static library that uses Objective-C++. When it is used in a straight Objective-C target, I get

```
Undefined symbols:
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
```

I can solve this by adding -lstdc++ to the target's "Other Linker Flags".

Question: Is there a way to specify this in the static library itself to make this step unnecessary? (Otherwise, I have to document it as an extra step for users of the library.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the answer is… no. Document the flags your library requires.